# Manipulate HTML using Marshal-like encoder

Tags: html, xml, go, xhtml

I have several html templates that I populate using a combination of css selectors([cascadia](http://github.com/andybalholm/cascadia)) and manually manipulating the html Nodes (using [x/html](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html)). Is there any better way to do this ? Something like the [xml](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/).Marshaller ?

I've tried using xhtml and along with the xml package(Decoder.AutoClose = H TMLAutoClose) but the issue is that on Decoding a lot of information/structure is lost (i.e. extra divs that are used for styling only and not included in the Data struct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT transform XML data with template and generates text or xhtml output. This might work for your use case https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp